# Flexbox footer not positioning correctly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am using Flexbox to display a header, middle and footer in a page. The footer is always at the bottom. The middle section stretches out using `flex-grow:1` so that all three elements together fit the page nicely.

This works perfectly on desktop browsers. On mobile browsers I can't get the layout to respond to the showing and hiding of url bar / tool bars of the mobile browser.

Using `100vh` or `100%` as the height does not take these bars on mobile into account.

I tried adding javascript to respond to window resize/scroll, but that seems to work only half of the time.

Using Javascript seems rather hacky, is there a CSS only way to take a mobile url bar into account?

How can I place a flex item at the bottom of the page on mobile, even when the url bar shows and hides?

```js
const app = document.querySelector("app")
window.addEventListener("resize", () => resize())
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => resize())

function resize(){
     console.log("resizing window")
     app.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

app, section {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

app {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.header {
  background-color:#4cc;
}

.middle {
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color:#cc4;
}

.footer {
  background-color:#4cc;
}
```

```html
<app>
    <section class="header">
        Header
    </section>

    <section class="middle">
        Middle
    </section>

    <section class="footer">
        Footer
    </section>
</app>
```

Comment: Maybe this will work for you ? https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

Comment: That seems to work at first, but when you scroll, the whole view scrolls up and shows an empty space below the footer. This is because the viewport height is now larger than the app height, so you can scroll.